# How to use the Django-Scheduler package?

Tags: python, django, django-scheduler

I am looking to use the [Django-Scheduler](https://github.com/llazzaro/django-scheduler) package in my Django project but am finding it difficult to understand how to actually implement the calendar so that it can be seen on the actual website. My website is meant to be a timetable scheduling system where users can login and use and edit there own timetable/calendar. I have already implemented the login and registrastion using [django registration redux](https://www.djangopackages.com/packages/p/django-registration-redux/). I have also already installed django-scheduler using pip and have edited my projects settings like so:

```
INSTALLED_APPS += ('schedule',)
```

add to

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS += (
    "django.core.context_processors.request",
)
```

This is explained on the [github](https://github.com/llazzaro/django-scheduler) page for django-scheduler. I have read through the documentation but am still not sure as to how to have a usable calendar on the page the user is sent to after logging in.

Could someone please explain to me as to how I can achieve this. What do I put in my projects url.py file for `django-scheduler` like eg the url for `django-calendarium`,

```
url(r'^calendar/', include('calendarium.urls')),
```

Do I have to create new templates etc.

Hope somebody can help ! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

this will serve you

```
url(r'^calendar/', include('schedule.urls')),
```

if you still to know more about the url, views, models and config of schedule check https://github.com/llazzaro/django-scheduler/tree/develop/schedule and https://github.com/llazzaro/django-scheduler/tree/develop/schedule/urls.py for